# Is using 'if user_signed?' many times, bad practise? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it a bad thing to check the value of user_signed_in? many times in a single page?

Or should it really be used once if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all.

All `user_signed_in?` does is:

```
def user_signed_in?
    !!current_user
end
```

and the `current_user` method "caches" its result in an instance variable.

So call `user_signed_in?` as many times as you need to.